# stpncpy.c:33: error while trying to compile dc3dd on Mac OSX MT Lion

Tags: xcode4.5

I'm trying to compile dc3dd which I downloaded from sourceforge.net.  I'm running Mac OS X MT Lion.  I have installed Xcode v4.5.2 and have installed the command line tools.  I have also installed MacPorts 2.1.2.  I ran 'sudo ./configure' as instructed which appeared to complete successfully.   When I run 'sudo make'.  I get the following error:

```
sudo make
Password:
make  all-recursive
Making all in lib
make  all-am
depbase=`echo stpncpy.o | sed 's|[^/]*$|.deps/&|;s|\.o$||'`;\
gcc -std=gnu99  -I.      -O2 -DDEFAULT_HASH_MD5 -MT stpncpy.o -MD -MP -MF $depbase.Tpo           -c -o stpncpy.o stpncpy.c &&\
    mv -f $depbase.Tpo $depbase.Po
stpncpy.c:33: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before numeric constant
stpncpy.c:33: error: expected ')' before '!=' token
stpncpy.c:33: error: expected ')' before '?' token
make[3]: *** [stpncpy.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have not been able to find anything every helpful on the internet.  I am not an experienced developer and haven't a clue what is wrong.  I have had previous versions of XCode on my computer (the old /Developer directory still exists).  I don't really know where to go from here.  Does anybody have some suggestions I can try?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In file : `./lib/stpncpy.c`

Change:

```
__stpncpy (char *dest, const char *src, size_t n)
```

to:

```
__stpcpy (char *dest, const char *src, size_t n)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've installed MacPorts then why not install the MacPorts version?

```
$ sudo port install dc3dd
```

Job done.

Comment: Thank you for the answer trojanfoe.  I would prefer to compile using my own trusted libraries.  I also want to be able to put this onto a bootable thumb drive.  If can't find a way to resolve the compile error then I may have to fall back on the MacPort version.

Comment: I went ahead with trojanfoe's suggestion and moved on.  Thanks!